# Get same IDs from Detail Table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables in my mysql database:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `RECIPES` (
  `recipes_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `text` varchar(2000) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `count_persons` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `duration` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `accepted` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`recipes_id`),
  KEY `recipes_user_fk` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=88 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `RECIPES_POS` (
  `recipes_pos_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `recipes_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ingredients_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ingredients_value` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`recipes_pos_id`),
  KEY `recipe_pos_rec_id` (`recipes_id`),
  KEY `recipes_pos_ingredient_fk` (`ingredients_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=58 ;
```

In the Recipe_Pos Table are many entries. This table shows what ingredients are used in the Recipe.

Now i want to find the recipe which contains incredients like powder and sugar:

```
SELECT r.recipes_id FROM RECIPES r, RECIPES_POS rp WHERE r.recipes_id = rp.recipes_id AND rp.ingredients_id =6 AND rp.ingredients_id =4
```

this statment is wrong because a entry in Recipe_Pos can'T contains both incredients.

Whats the right query? It should works with only 1 incredient and more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select r.recipes_id
from RECIPES r
inner join RECIPES_POS rp on r.recipes_id = rp.recipes_id
where rp.ingredients_id in (4, 6)
group by r.recipes_id
having count(distinct rp.ingredients_id) = 2
```